# autocomplete-like feature in terminal (ROS2) that shows the "options" for that command typed in

Tags: command-line

It's not quite autocomplete but on the ROS2 course on O'Reilly, the instructor types part of the command, presses Enter and the terminal shows any and all commands for which what has been typed before pressing Enter is a substring of the actual command.

Here is an example

[image: autocomplete pic]

```
cd /usr/share/col
```

gets him several that start like that and among them he chooses to type in

```
cd /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete...
```

`...` because he types in the subdirectory after that

How do I get this functionality on my terminal?

Comment: Usally `TAB` `TAB` shows the different possibilities for autocomplete.

Comment: ```yck33@nyck33-VB-Ubu22ROS:~/ros2_ws$ history | g

Display all 242 possibilities? (y or n)

``` that does not really work. @Marco

Answer (score 0):

It's press TAB twice in quick succession, in my use case in the ROS2 course, I type

```
ros2 run my_py_pkg //tab twice now
```

giving me a list of executables that I can run with that command

```
nyck33@nyck33-VB-Ubu22ROS:~$ ros2 run my_py_pkg 

--prefix

py_node

robot_news_station

//then run the command I want

nyck33@nyck33-VB-Ubu22ROS:~$ ros2 run my_py_pkg robot_news_station
```